# Kubernetes pod hangs when NFS PVC becomes unavailable

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nfs

Is there a way to prevent POD from hanging when NFS PVC share becomes unavailable? Once its get stuck only option is to delete the cluster node and recreate it.

POD doesn't respond to anything and can't be deleted even if NFS is back online. Forcefully deleting the pod gets stuck in terminating state. Draining the node doesn't fix it either. Only option is to delete the cluster node where the pod is stuck and start a new node.

PVC also cannot be deleted until NFS is back online but we need to patch the pvc before deleting.

```
kubectl patch pvc prod-nfs-pvc -n prod -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```

This is how I have setup NFS on a VM which is acquired by PVC.

```
/prod-nfs 10.49.56.0/16(rw,sync,no_root_squash,insecure)
```

PV and PVC yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: prod-nfs-data
  labels:
    name: prod-nfs-data
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: "/prod-nfs/data"
    server: "10.49.56.6"
    readOnly: false
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: prod-nfs-data-pvc
  namespace: prod
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: prod-nfs-data
```

Comment: Have you tried force deleting the pod with --force=true and --grace-period=0 ?

Comment: yea I tried. Still it doesn't delete

Comment: I was able to replicate, but --force did delete the pod for me. I create a VM with NFS share, I created pv, pvc and could of pods with nfs share mounted. I tried deleting the pod, it would stuck in Terminating state. Then I'd run `k delete pod/nfs-pod-1 --force` and the pod was gone with the following message: `warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.
pod "nfs-pod-1" force deleted`. I then checked the node and the workload was gone too.

Comment: @John, any progress with this issue ?

Comment: on OCP 4.8 (same as K8s 1.21) ; same issue but force delete of POD worked and after that could remove the PV and PVC without any further action.